# Iterating ngrx8 reducers

Tags: arrays, angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-reducers

Interface:

```
export interface IClient extends Array<IClient> {
  client_name: string
}
```

Actions:

```
export const addClientSuccess = createAction(
  '[CLIENT] ADD_CLIENT_COMPLETE',
  props<{ client_name: IClient }>()
);
```

Reducers:

```
export interface ClientState {
    client_name: IClient[]
}

export const clientInitialState: ClientState = {
    client_name: []
}

export const clientReducer = createReducer(
clientInitialState,
on(ClientActionTypes.addClientSuccess,(state, {client_name}) => ({
  ...state,
  client_name: [...client_name]
})
```

))

Effects:

```
addClient = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions.pipe(
      ofType(ClientActionTypes.addClient),
      switchMap(({ client }) => {
        return this.clientService.addClient(client).pipe(
          map((res) => ClientActionTypes.addClientSuccess(res)),
          catchError(error => {
            return of(ClientActionTypes.addClientFailure({ error }))
          })
        );
      })
    );
  });
```

With the above code I'm trying to append arrays to client_name but the value I enter gets separated into multiple values inside an array, I have attached the redux store on how it gets iterated.

[image]

For example if I have test and testing entered it should print a ['test',"testing"]

Comment: Why are you extending Iclient interface?

Comment: If I don't use it I get an error like "Type must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator"

Comment: In your interface you defined string and destructing string into array that why you are getting array of letters

Comment: thanks, can you please let me know how do I update the interface so that it works as expected.

Comment: Is client_name array of string or single name?

Comment: single name , like I have a add button enter the client_name and when I use it again, it should get appended to the previous list of client_name ["name1","name2"]

Comment: can you share your state interface?

Comment: Sure, I have updated the reducers state in the question

Answer (score 1):

youre doing it wrong.

1. your interface should not be extending `Array<IClient>`. its a simple string.

   `export interface IClient {
     client_name: string;
   }`
2. your state should contain meaningful names: `client_name**s**: IClient[]`

   `export interface ClientState {
       client_names: IClient[]
   }`

   `export const clientInitialState: ClientState = {
       client_names: []
   }`
3. your reducer should be 
   a. configured correctly, to have type safety.
   b. your client_name array, should contain previous clients initialized before adding a new client. use the spread operator.

   `export const clientReducer = createReducer(
   clientInitialState,
   on(ClientActionTypes.addClientSuccess,(state, action) => ({
     ...state,
     client_names: [...state.client_names, action.client_name]
   })`
4. your effect should also be configured correctly:

   `addClient$ = createEffect(() => {
       return this.actions.pipe(
         ofType(ClientActionTypes.addClient),
         switchMap((action) => {
           return this.clientService.addClient(action.client_name).pipe(
             map((res) => ClientActionTypes.addClientSuccess({ client_name: res})),
             catchError(error => {
               return of(ClientActionTypes.addClientFailure({ error }))
             })
           );
         })
       );
     });`

I haven't tested this code, so use your intellisense to fix mistypes if any.

- sorry on the `code` instead of code-blocks formatting, SO 4 spaces isn't working properly for some reason.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort , I have followed the exact code as urs , I get the error like "ERROR TypeError: state.client_names is not iterable"

Comment: double check your state model

Comment: Thanks. Ya, I'm getting the response on effects as string correctly. Should be issues with the state.

Comment: What is the response are you getting from service?